# The Text Formatting Toolbar symfony

Tags: symfony, toolbar, text-formatting

Hiii,
I wanted to know if there are Text Formatting Toolbar for symfony to integrate into my textareas.

Someone can help or show a path.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are looking for something like [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/).

Your question actually has nothing to deal with Symfony2 since it is client-side oriented.

Comment: Thanks but can you know if sfWndPlugin of symfony 1.0 works in symfony 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this bundle

https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle

It adds several new form fields to symfony forms, including a Tinymce form field which is what you need.